# Use magnet to attach external usb soundcard to case "good" idea?

Tags: sound-card

A bit "extraordinary" for sure and I wanted to ask if i have to expect some bad coming out of it ^^
I want to use this external soundcard:
https://www.thomann.de/de/focusrite_scarlett_2i2_3rd_gen.htm

And this magnet:
https://www.amazon.de/Jewan-Magnete-Seltenerdmagnete-Seltener-Magnets/dp/B08B58X1GY/ref=sr_1_21?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=magnet&qid=1626041230&sr=8-21

I know electronics and magnetism dont necessarily like each other ^^
But I heard that its for example a myth that a magnet can scramble the data on an HDD(it can damage mechanics though).
So I wonder if I can safely use such a magnet to firmly attach the soundcard to the top of my fractal design R5 case? Or will it cause significant disturbances on the electronics side or even damage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, magnets and electricity do not mix.

I will start off by saying, this might work perfectly well.

However, there is no way for us to know how well shielded the case of your computer and the case of this device is.  Also, we dont know how strong the magnet is.  Nor do we know if there is a component within the magnetic field that would be affected by the magnet.
However, if it is strong enough to hold that device securely, I would just recommend against it.

If you want it to be detachable, use [Velcro tape](https://www.google.com/search?q=velcro%20tape&oq=velcro%20tape&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j0i457j0l6.2950j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  It is removeable and will not damage either case.  Additionally, a magnet might not even work, if either metal is not steel.  It could be that the case of your sound card is aluminum and therefore, not magnetic.

> But I heard that its for example a myth that a magnet can scramble the data on an HDD

This is ***NOT*** a myth.  This is in fact *very* true.  It is literally how hard disk drives work.  Hard drives are a type of [magnetic media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_storage) and magnets are used to write the data.  A magnet can can erase a disk and there are devices that use magnets to specifically erase hard drives.